# In Django, how to code else statement to reload same page and trigger error message pop-up?

Tags: django, if-statement, popupwindow

I am writing a Django view that should allow users to export selected records to Excel by selecting the records they'd like to export, then clicking an Export button on the Django Admin change list page. I have an `if/else` statement for this and I'd like my `else:` to basically reload the same change list page, but trigger a popup window error message if the user clicks "Export" without having selected any records to export. Something like "No records selected to export. Please try again." How would I accomplish this? TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [messages documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/). Basically, you should add something like this to your template:

```
{% if messages %}
    <div class='messages'>

    <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{% if "html_safe" in message.tags %}{{ message|safe }}{% else %}{{ message }}{% endif %}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    </div>
{% endif %}
```

And in your views.py, you could do something like this:

```
messages.error(request, "This is an error message")
return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
```

Take the html with a mountain of salt, I'm not good as a frontender/designer.

Comment: thank you! Will check out the messages docs and give this a shot.